# Why does Settings.app make reference to requiring a SIM card for the Auto Call setting of Emergency SOS, and not for the entire feature altogether?

Tags: settings

When navigating to Settings/Emergency SOS on my iPhone 11 Pro, below the "Auto Call" control the hint states that "Auto Call requires a SIM card". I'm trying to establish why this text wouldn't be displayed when referencing the entire Emergency SOS feature; surely a SIM is also required if simply sliding the Emergency SOS slider to call the Emergency Services too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Emergency numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_telephone_number#Emergency_numbers_and_mobile_telephones) can be called without a SIM card in may countries & many phones, including iPhones are designed to allow this, even from a locked screen.
All other numbers need a valid SIM, active account etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, in the case of a country that requires a SIM to be inserted into the phone to make emergency calls, should the GUI not say something along the lines of "A SIM card must be inserted to make emergency calls" or similar - rather than singling out the Auto Call setting?

Comment: You'd have to ask Apple that one.